# DNS Issue - Different results-

Tags: networking, dns

I'm a n00b in DNS and that stuff, so I would like to know why I'm having different results for a reverse lookup in two systems:

```
     alekz@debian:~$ dig -x 177.247.158.74

    ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> -x 177.247.158.74
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 26325
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;74.158.247.177.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    247.177.in-addr.arpa.   787 IN  SOA unix.megared.net.mx. root.megared.net.mx. 7 3600 900 604800 86400

    ;; Query time: 57 msec
    ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
    ;; WHEN: Thu Apr 20 17:56:44 CDT 2017
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
```

And in another system, I'm having the host **customer-COL-158-74.megared.net.mx** which is exactly what I was looking for.

```
alekz@Lydia:~$ dig -x 177.247.158.74

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian <<>> -x 177.247.158.74
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 4380
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 13

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;74.158.247.177.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
74.158.247.177.in-addr.arpa. 84747 IN   PTR customer-COL-158-74.megared.net.mx.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
in-addr.arpa.       57647   IN  NS  d.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       57647   IN  NS  a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       57647   IN  NS  e.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       57647   IN  NS  b.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       57647   IN  NS  c.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       57647   IN  NS  f.in-addr-servers.arpa.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  A   199.212.0.73
a.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  AAAA    2001:500:13::73
b.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  A   199.253.183.183
b.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  AAAA    2001:500:87::87
c.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  A   196.216.169.10
c.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  AAAA    2001:43f8:110::10
d.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  A   200.10.60.53
d.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  AAAA    2001:13c7:7010::53
e.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  A   203.119.86.101
e.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  AAAA    2001:dd8:6::101
f.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  A   193.0.9.1
f.in-addr-servers.arpa. 57647   IN  AAAA    2001:67c:e0::1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 21 00:58:19 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 480
```

Can someone explain me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to complain to whoever runs `megared.net.mx`.

Adding the flag `+trace` to the `dig` command line shows the whole lookup process. That tells us that the authoritative name servers for the domain `247.177.in-addr.arpa.` are `ns1.megared.net.mx` and `ns2.megared.net.mx`. And if we send a `PTR` query for `74.158.247.177.in-addr.arpa` directly to those, they do not give us the same answer. One of them answers `customer-COL-158-74.megared.net.mx.` while the other one says `NXDOMAIN`. So a normal lookup will randomly get one of those answers depending on which name server the resolver happens to choose for the final step.

Whoever runs those two name servers need to fix them so they both have the same data in them.

Comment: Thank you so much Calle, what you said is true, I send today the same dig from both servers and the response is actually random. Cheers!